# Firebase Realtime Database - how to manage database rules using java sdk

Tags: java, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

I would like to set the database rules for my realtime database using the java sdk. I created a FirebaseDatabase object but I wasn't able to find out how to get/set the database rules using it.

```
val options = FirebaseOptions.builder()
    .setDatabaseUrl("https://my-database.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/")
    .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(File("/path/tom/my/key.json").inputStream()))
    .build()
val defaultApp = FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options)

val defaultDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(defaultApp);
// and here I would like to fetch the current rules and be able to set the new one
```

I've found this piece of docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/app-management and tried

```
println(defaultDatabase.getReference(".settings/rules.json"))
```

but I got only

> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Invalid Firebase Database path: .settings/rules.json. Firebase Database paths must not contain '.', '#', '$', '[', or ']'

How to do it ?

Comment: The Admin Node.js SDK provides `getRules()` and `setRules()` APIs for this, but they are not available in Java yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.settings` pseudo-node is not exposed in the Java Admin SDK. If you want to manipulate the rules from your Java code, you'll have to call the REST API from there.

Comment: do you know whether the REST API is available for databases placed in Europe also?

Comment: Yeah, that should work. If not, let me know (with an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).